# In C++ what is a value semantic class? I see class descriptions like "This component implements a fully value-semantic container class"

Tags: c++, class, containers

The example I have is a pretty big exhaustive class. Can someone give a small example too?

Answer (score 4):

It means that the container contains copies of the things that were added to it, in other words it contains values as opposed to pointers or references to the contained objects. Examples of such containers are those in the C++ Standard Library, such as std::vector and std::map.

Comment: OK. So what is the advantage/disadvantage of that? In other words, what if std::vector was not a value semantic container?

Comment: It would be fantastically difficult to use (and to actually implement). For example if you  pushed stack allocated and heap allocated objects into the vector, the vector would have to somehow work out the completely different ownership and management semantics for each of them. As it is, there is no problem - the vector stores copies, which are trivial to manage.